# Python unable to grab values from dict file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file containing dictionaries, one per line, of user information:

```
{'username': 'jsmith', 'fullname': 'John Smith', 'email': 'jmith@example.com'}
{'username': 'ajones', 'fullname': 'Betty Jones', 'email': 'bjones@example.com'}
{'username': 'pmills', 'fullname': 'Paul Mills', 'email': 'pmills@example.com'}
```

My python script needs to iterate thru this file and assign each value in each dictionary to a variable. The script looks like this:

```
import subprocess
import ast

# iterate through users file line by line
with open('users.txt') as users:
  for line in users:
    d_line = ast.literal_eval(line)
    for k,v in d_line.items():
      un = v['username']
      full = v['fullname']
      mail = v['email']
      print (un, full, mail)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "admin-add.py", line 13, in <module>
    un = v['username']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Not sure why it is still treating the line as a string.

Comment: For `k="username"`, the corresponding `v` would be `"jsmith"`. That's what `dict.items()` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just needs to iterate each line in file and evaluate it as dictionaries then get the value of each keys

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('users.txt') as users:
    for line in users:
        d_line = literal_eval(line)
        un, full, mail = d_line['username'], d_line['fullname'], d_line['email']
        print(un, full, mail)
```

Comment: Thanks @arifa chan, your code clean and precise. Used it and works perfectly.